# Scale in buying positions in Amibroker backtesting

Tags: trading, back-testing, amibroker

I have a simple backtesting code in Amibroker. It looks something like this;

```
Buy = BuySignal();
Sell = SellSignal();
```

My equity is $10000. 
This code works but the limitation is that when it buys, the entire equity $10000 is sunk into the buy. What I want is something like this;

When `BuySignal()` is generated, buy $1000 or 10% of equity. Keep buying this amount whenever this `BuySignal()` is generated. If `SellSignal()` is generated, sell entire position.

How can I modify the code to do scaling-in of buying positions?

I am using Amibroker ver6.28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
PosQty = 10; 
SetOption("MaxOpenPositions", PosQty );
PositionSize = -100/PosQty;

Buy = IIf(BuySignal(), sigScaleIn, 0);
```